# Need information about the parent of a child component for conditional rendering in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

So, I have two projects, say ParentA and ParentB. I need to load a modal that shows different text when loaded in ParentA project and a different text when loaded from ParentB. The modal is present in a common folder so that both parents can use it to render. The one solution I came up with is to pass a parameter when calling the modal from either of the parents which can then be used in the modal class to identify which of the parents is calling and based on that, load the data. But the modal is used in a lot of pages in both projects and so I wanted to confirm if my way is the correct or is there a better, cleaner solution to this.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show some code ? That would make it much easier to give advice. However a bool [Parameter] seems fine here. Or you could create 2 Modals that share parts of the logic. That would make it easier for future changes. But without the real implementation its hard to say.

Comment: Please define different text.  If it's just some text then why not pass that in as a parameter?  You could also use the 'ChildContent' concept to pass in the formatted content.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what component templating is for which is used quite a bit in Microsofts's standard Blazor components e.g. [`<AuthorizeView>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authorizeview-component) as well as in all component libaries.

Your child component needs a Parameter of type [`RenderFragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or [`RenderFragement<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (in case you want to also set some context). A [`RenderFragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is an in-memory representation of a UI segment and you can pass Razor code to it.

Here a simple example of a child component, here a Card, which accepts a [`RenderFragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

`Card.razor`

```
<div class="my-card">
     <div class="card-title">
          @Title
     </div>
     <div class="card-content">
          @ChildContent
     </div>
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

}
```

And here an example of two parent components that render different content within the child.

`Parent1.razor`

```
<Card Title="Parent 1 card">
    @* Here goes everything that the parent wants to render within the child  *@
    <div>Rendered from Parent 1</div>
</Card>
```

`Parent2.razor`

```
<Card Title="Parent 2 card">
    @* Here goes everything that the parent wants to render within the child  *@
    <div>Rendered from Parent 2</div>
</Card>
```

Without any styling just plugged in into a page of the standard Blazor template this would look something like this:
`Counter.razor`

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Test</PageTitle>
<Parent1 />
<Parent2 />
```

[image: Blazor - Compoent templating example]

For more detailed explanation and some real-world and more comlex examples see:

- [MS docs - ASP.NET Core Blazor templated components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [Blazor University - Templating components with RenderFragments](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/)
- [MudBlazor - *Collapse* component](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/tree/dev/src/MudBlazor/Components/Collapse): shows usage of `RenderFragment` within a component library
- [MS - AuthorizeView](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Authorization/src/AuthorizeViewCore.cs): implementation of the built-in `<AuthorizeView>` component by Microsoft using [`RenderFragment<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: This is flexible but "the modal is used in a lot of pages" and I think the OP doesn't want to repeat the ChildContent everywhere.

Comment: In that case OP can still use my approach and just create a component thatsupplies the ChildContent. Then this component can be re-used where required.

Comment: Yes, a wrapper component could work but it's a 'modal' so you may have to pass a lot of other params. Or not, it's not clear.